# How are transactions handled in integrationtest of legacy code

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-test

Im trying to understand what is going on when im using `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` in my integration tests when trying to rollback changes made by legacy code.

The legacy code uses `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to communicate with the database. The transaction manager is of type `DataSourceTransactionManager` and my datasource is of type `DriverManagerDataSource`.

This is the overall structure of my test class.

```
@Begin
//Make initial setup of database using `JDBCTemplate` from `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.

@Test
//Call legacy code that makes inserts to database.
```

**My question is if my assuption is wrong that by extending `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` I make all my tests transactional. This has the expected effect that all changes made directly by my testfunction AND in legacy code called from the test function transactional and implicitly rolled back at the end of the tests???**

*Some observations I made are:
The `@Begin` function works as expected when used with testfunctions that does not call legacy code that makes changes. In this case the changes made in `@Begin` are rolledback.
If however I use `@Begin` with `@Test` functions calling legacy code that makes changes both the changes made by `@Begin` and `@Test` does not get rolled back! The log message printed dos state that the transactions is initated and that the rollback is successful but im not getting the expected behavior.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Spring TestContext Framework* (TCF) manages what I call *test-managed transactions*. The TCF does **not** manage *application-managed transactions*.

If you have code that it is managing its own transactions (e.g., via Spring's `TransactionTemplate` or some other programmatic means), then those interactions with the database will not be rolled back by the TCF.

For further details, consult the [Test-managed Transactions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-test-managed-transactions) section of the reference manual *or* slide #43 from my [Testing with Spring: An Introduction](http://www.slideshare.net/sbrannen/testing-with-spring-an-introduction) presentation.

Furthermore, you naturally have to ensure that the `DataSource` used by the TCF is the exact same `DataSource` used by the Spring `DataSourceTransactionManager` and your legacy code. If all of your legacy code uses Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, that code should participate in the correct transaction. Otherwise, you'll need to use Spring's `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource)` to ensure that legacy code works with Spring-managed and test-managed transactions.